# What purpose does this code change serve?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the **implications** / **side effects** / **advantages** of a recent code change someone made. The change is as follows:

**Original**

```
static List<type1> Data;
```

**Modified**

```
static List<type1> & getData (void)
{
    static List<type1> * iList = new List<type1>;
    return * iList;
}
#define Data getData()
```

What purpose could the change serve?

Comment: maybe to avoid some sort of static initialization problem?

Comment: `#define Data ...` is just asking for trouble

Comment: @Lol4t0: could you please explain a little bit more regarding your comment? How is it not thread safe?

Comment: The problem with `#define Data ...` is that macros are not constrained by scope and will wreak havoc if any other code uses a type or member called `Data`. I suffered from a macro wreaking havoc this week; the `<string.h>` header was included in some old code that contained `extern char *strdup(const char *);`, and the macro expansion of `strdup()` meant that the declaration there was completely screwed up. I fixed the code with `extern char *(strdup)(const char *);` which prevents the function-like macro being expanded. Had the macro been `#define strdup __strdup` it would still be broken!

Answer (score 4):

The benefit to the revision that I can see is an issue of 'initialization time'.

The old code triggered an initialization before `main()` is called.

The new code does not trigger initialization until `getData()` is called for the first time; if the function is never called, you never pay to initialize a variable you didn't use.  The (minor) downside is that there is an initialization check in the generated code each time the function is used, and there is a function call every time you need to access the list of data.

Comment: What about value lifetime once it is initialized? Will that be the same?

Comment: Once initialized, it lasts 'forever' (until the program terminates).  It should be destroyed cleanly, I believe, if the program exits under control.  (Oh, but it is dynamically allocated; maybe it just 'leaks' when the program exits?  Such a 'leak' is pretty harmless unless the data type that is in the list acquires resources that need to be formally released when the program exits.)

Comment: @Lazer: Yes. the lifetime is same as in case of original code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: As the only real object is a pointer, the list will never be deleted and thus never destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a variable with static duration, it is created when the application is initialized. When the application terminates the object is destroyed. It is not possible to control the order in which different objects are created.

The change will make the object be created when it is first used, and (as it is allocated dynamically) it will never be destroyed.

This can be a good thing if other objects need this objects when they are destroyed.

*Update*

The original code accessed the object using the variable `Data`. The new code does not have to be modified in any way. When the code use `Data` it will, in fact, be using the *macro* `Data`, which will be expanded into `getData()`. This function will return a reference to the actual (dynamically allocated object). In practice, the new code will work as a drop-in replacement for the old code, with the only noticable difference being what I described in the original answer above.

Comment: Yes the object will not be destroyed, but how will it be accessed?

Comment: It will be accessed whenever somebody calls `getData`, Lazer.

Answer (score 1):

Delaying construction until the first use of `Data` avoids the "[static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14)".

Making some guesses about your `List`,... the default-constructed `Data` is probably an empty list of `type1` items, so it's probably not at great risk of causing the fiasco in question.  But perhaps someone felt it better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why that change was made :

- [to prevent the static order initialization fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15)
- to delay the initialization of the static variable (for whatever reason)